# Fedora: Create multiple workspaces with a script

Tags: scripting, fedora, window, workspaces

At the moment I'm using Fedora with Gnome.

I want to create a script which will be able to start the applications on different workspaces.

For me it's clear that I could create a script which just oppens the different applications in the actual workscpae/screen.
For working efficient I would like to start the applications in a specified workspace.
For example:
I want to start my email-client on the first workspace. On the second workspace should be the relevant things to work with. And on a third workspace I'd like to have some communication tools and so on. 
I hope my idea is clear enough, otherwise just ask!

Is there a solution without installing other tools?

Thanks and kind regards